# Unable to connect to port in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am getting this error after running `Cassandra` command and then trying to run `cqlsh` in another command prompt window. Can you please let me know that how to solve this?

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':
> error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error:
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it")})

Comment: check if service is running or not?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's usually a good idea to search the site before asking a question.  Case-in-point, a search for "cassandra unable to connect" yields 368 results. - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cassandra+unable+to+connect&searchOn=3

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible causes for it:
(a) either Cassandra is not running, or
(b) the process is not bound to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`).

Cassandra is listening for clients/apps on `rpc_address` (or `native_transport_address` for DSE).

You can check the IP address + port that Cassandra is listening on by running either of these 2 commands:

```
$ netstat -tnlp
```

```
$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN
```

Cheers!